# React error with code splitting (Argument type function() is not assignable to parameter type)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, code-splitting

I am trying to split my code using React.Lazy() with Route-based code splitting (https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)

For example that's the component (Reports.jsx)

```
import React from 'react';

const Reports = () => {
    return <div>Reports</div>;
};

export default Reports;
```

And I have in my  route.js:

```
const LazyReports =  React.lazy(() => import ('../../containers/team/reports/Reports'));
```

and I'm getting this error, and the bundle is not loaded.

Argument type function(): Promise<{readonly default?: function()}> is not assignable to parameter type () => Promise<{default: ComponentType}>   Type Promise<{readonly default?: function()}> is not assignable to type Promise<{default: ComponentType}>

I figured out it's not related to the routing, but I don't know why it doesn't recognize the component as "ComponentType"

Comment: ended up with the error Argument type function(): Promise<{readonly default?: function()}> is not assignable to parameter type () => Promise<{default: ComponentType}>   Type Promise<{readonly default?: function()}> is not assignable to type Promise<{default: ComponentType}>

being irrelevant,

Comment: The problem was I had to rerun 'npm start' and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the complete code but below code is working fine with lazy code syntax. I feel above seem ok to me. Hoping the container code is only have above component code.

One thing you can do , delete the build folder and build again with yarn build/npm build.

Below is simple code without any router /redux.

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const LazyReports =  React.lazy(() => import ('./Reports'))

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <LazyReports/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: const Reports = () => {
    return <div>Reports</div>;
};

export default Reports;

Comment: Thanks for the help, look at my comment for the solution I've found